# How to achieve a page turning in a facebook canvas app using either javascript or vb.codebehind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I found multiple suggestions on how to turn pages on the internet, unfortunately I was unable to implement one of them so far to achieve a page turning from my default.aspx page to a secondpage.aspx page. I have tried the following:

calling the following vb.codebehind methods using the onclick.event of an asp:LinkButton

```
    Protected Sub OpenSecondPage()
      Server.Transfer("secondpage.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub OpenSecondPage()
      Response.Redirect("secondpage.aspx")
    End Sub
```

In both cases I get an error message: "this content cannot be displayed in a frame"

The same error occurs using these javascript functions:

```
    function GetFacebookId() {
          FB.api('/me', function (response) {
              document.getElementById("fbId").value = response.id;
              document.getElementById("fbName").value = response.name;
              window.location.replace="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/secondpage.aspx";
          })
      }        

     function GetFacebookId() {
          FB.api('/me', function (response) {
              document.getElementById("fbId").value = response.id;
              document.getElementById("fbName").value = response.name;
              window.location.href="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/secondpage.aspx";
          })
      }
```

I also tried simulating a buttonclick.event with javascript which called the vb.codebehind sub. This seemed to work from my pc, but apparently this is blocked by common security settings on browsers and also generally frowned upon.

I just started my second year of job training and I am out of ideas at this point. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

This is the code of my secondpage.aspx site:

```
     <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Woerterbuch.aspx.vb" Inherits="Facebook2SeitenLoesung.secondpage" %>
     <%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=somenumber" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" tagprefix="dx" %>
     <%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=somenumber" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" tagprefix="dx" %>

          <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <head runat="server">
          <title></title>
          </head>
```

Comment: _“In both cases I get an error message: "this content cannot be displayed in a frame"”_ – that’s most likely because the page you are trying to display prevents that by sending an `X-Frame-Options` header.

Comment: I tried searching for x-frame-options in my project and could not find any in either of my websites. Where would these x-frame-options usually be located?

Comment: Just call your page directly in the main browser window, and check the response headers.

Comment: This is what I received:      
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
      Cache-Control:private
      Content-Length:5311
      Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
      Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
      X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
      X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
      Date:Thu, 17 Oct 2013 12:00:52 GMT
      Connection:close